# Using external stepper driver

Tags: marlin, stepper

I need to add two external stepper drivers to my MKS Gen L board. I am using `E1` as an extra Y-axis and that is working great. I have three Z motors and I want to move them independently if I can.

I am using:

- pins `63`, `40`, and `42` for `Z2`, and;
- pins `59`, `64`, and `44` for `Z3`.

I step up the pins in Marlin and set it to use three motors but when try to move Z only the normal Z motor moves, i.e. the default on-board z stepper driver.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: How did you define the pins for the extra steppers, please add the lines you added in your `pins_[board].h`, e.g. I expect you defined `Zx_yyy_PIN` for all pins.

Comment: I did that, added pins for Y2 and Y3 to the pins I want to use.

Comment: Please update the question with the lines you added, and where, the MKS GEN L (version ?) is a RAMPS derivative, possibly are the pins redefined. Adding the information gives others more information to answer, it is basically guesswork at the moment. Have you chosen a driver type for Z2 and Z3?